# Calling Spring Service (import java.net.URL.* package) POST its calling but getting java.io.FileNotFoundException on response

Tags: java, web-services, spring, url, spring-mvc

I'm trying to setup a basic call to a Spring service using the URL package so that I can do it through a POST rather than get.

Client code (the code calling the spring service):

```
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("testStringFromGWT", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/spring-hibernate-mysql/test/test1");

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            // Process line...
        }
        wr.close();
        rd.close();
```

The Spring service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loggedInUniversal_logout(
        Model model,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(value = "inputString", required = true) String inputString)
        throws InterruptedException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    System.out.println("Request made from Client..." + inputString);

    model.addAttribute("token", "It works");
    return "token";
}
```

When I try this I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/spring-hibernate-mysql/test/test1
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, I am able to confirm that the call is being passed through properly to Spring as I can see the line being printed `"Request made from Client..." + inputString` but then I get the FileNotFoundException on the client. I pieced this together from looking at tutorials so I guess I am missing something here, would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the output stream before trying to read from the input stream in your example above.

As an alternative, use a http client library like [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) or [Resty](http://beders.github.com/Resty/Resty/Overview.html).

With Resty, your client code would look like this:

```
Resty r = new Resty();
String result = r.text(url).toString();
```

for a GET
and for a POST using a simple form:

```
r.text(url,form(yourformdata)).toString();
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Resty

Comment: Awesome, thanks this helps a lot, I am new to doing these sorts of calls within Java

Comment: Jochen, Resty looks cool but I'm not quite sure I understand how to do what I am trying to do, I'm not trying to post from a form, rather say that I have `String someString = "something to post"` and I want to POST it to the server where I designate its variable name also as `someString` so that Spring can interpret it as such, I would appreciate any info on how to do this, I am looking at the examples on the Resty page but can't seem to figure it out

Comment: I see this `data("appid","YahooDemo"),data("query", "Resty+java"), data("results", "10")` part in the examples but am not quite sure what the `data` is as its not offering anything to import in my IDE for that

Comment: what content type is your rest service expecting? application/x-www-form-urlencoded or application/form-data? In the latter case, you would use form(data("yourkey", "yourvalue"),...) or form(data("yourkey", content(bytes)) in case your value is not a string.  Keep in mind that in the code examples I used static imports so the calls to data/form are actually calls to Resty.data(...) and Resty.form(...)

Comment: `import static us.monoid.web.Resty.*`

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean, the service is just expecting a string

Comment: is it expecting just text/plain? in this case do: text(url, content(yourstring))